# Subcategories of disabled Categories are still accessible

Tags: category, magento2.2

I have the following scenario:

```
+ Primary Category       <---- DISABLED
|
+-- Secondary Category   <---- ENABLED
|
+---- Tertiary Category  <---- ENABLED
```

So the primary category is not web-accessible, and does not show in the navigation. However the secondary and tertiary is accessible if you have the link bookmarked or find it via a web search.

Is this normal behavior? What is the proper way to disable all children of a parent category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a feature not a bug. 
At least, this is what i gather [reading the documentation.](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/category-hidden.html)

Well, if you think, in a category tree, if a parent gets disabled or hidden, it doesn't mean children should also.

Think about those children categories linked all around pages, static blocs or even widgets. Having to disable them manually, means you know what you're doing, and you don't risk downtimes with your cateogries.

This is my point of view, i think that it's hard to give a more technical opinion as this feature is provided by default from the Magento architects.

Comment: To me, it I think it is more confusing for a parent category to exist, yet be inaccessible. First, I think its only natural to expect children to be hidden or disabled if the parent is the same. Second, if I'm a user at the location `Cell Phones > Apple Phones > Apple Accessories > Apple Cases`, and `Apple Phones` is both disabled and not shown in navigation, then the breadcrumb will show `Home > Cell Phones > Apple Cases`. Yet if you navigate up to `Cell Phones`, you will not find `Apple Cases`.

Comment: @andyjv I got your point. Yep it's somehow confusing. I never thought before about it so thank you for opening the discussion. Maybe somebody else from the Magento community knows something more.

Comment: Magento support did confirm to me that this is the intended behavior